# Repeated JOINs based on months

Tags: sql-server

This is a SQL Query I wrote quickly to get me a report for the number of PayPal purchases for each month, the database is of my own construction that's based on data that has been imported.

```
SELECT
    Items.ItemTitle,
    February.Cnt As February,
    March.Cnt As March,
    April.Cnt As April,
    May.Cnt As May,
    June.Cnt As June,
    July.Cnt As July,
    August.Cnt As August,
    September.Cnt As September
FROM

( SELECT DISTINCT ItemTitle FROM PayPalHistory ) As Items

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-02-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-03-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS February

ON Items.ItemTitle = February.ItemTitle

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-03-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-04-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS March

ON Items.ItemTitle = March.ItemTitle

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-04-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-05-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS April

ON Items.ItemTitle = April.ItemTitle

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-05-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-06-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS May

ON Items.ItemTitle = May.ItemTitle

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-06-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-07-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS June

ON Items.ItemTitle = June.ItemTitle

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-07-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-08-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS July

ON Items.ItemTitle = July.ItemTitle

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-08-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-09-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS August

ON Items.ItemTitle = August.ItemTitle

LEFT OUTER JOIN

( SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt FROM PayPalHistory WHERE
    DateTimeUtc >= '2014-09-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-10-01' AND Net > 0.00
GROUP BY ItemTitle ) AS September

ON Items.ItemTitle = September.ItemTitle

ORDER BY
    ItemTitle ASC
```

Are you seeing a pattern here? :)

Is there any way I can have a loop or some other construct to eliminate repeating the `LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT ... )` code?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need a `PIVOT`. First make table query with ItemTitle, Month, Count. After that try to `PIVOT` or use similar technique. something like [this](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 3):

I've not actually written a PIVOT before, but in theory it looks like this:

```
SELECT ItemTitle, [1] AS January, [2] AS February, [3] AS March, [4] AS April, [5] AS May
      , [6] AS June, [7] AS July, [8] AS August, [9] AS September, [10] AS October 
      [11] AS November, [12] AS December
FROM 
(
   SELECT ItemTitle, Month(DateTimeUtc) AS [Month]
   FROM PayPalHistory 
   WHERE DateTimeUtc >= '2014-01-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2015-01-01' AND Net > 0.00
) p
PIVOT
( 
   COUNT ([Month]) FOR [Month] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
) AS pvt;
```

I'm not quite sure that I'm handling the month column names correctly, or how Sql Server will even handle this integers as column names here, or how it will handle the `*` instead of a column name in the aggregate function. You may need to project the month number to a string as part of query nested in the FROM clause to make it work. It will definitely need some tweaking, but it wouldn't take too much to get this working if I had your real data to work with.

Alternatively, you can use a nested GROUP BY and the SUM(CASE) method to get it down to a single join. The single join is still necessary to avoid NULLs/missing items in the results, and could also perhaps be avoided by adding `COALESCE()` functions to the each of the month columns:

```
SELECT b.ItemTitle,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 1  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As January,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 2  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As February,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 3  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As March,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 4  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As April,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 5  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As May,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 6  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As June,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 7  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As July,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 8  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As August,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 9  THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As September,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 10 THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As October,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 11 THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As November,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Month] = 12 THEN Cnt ELSE 0 END) As December 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ItemTitle FROM PayPalHistory) b
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT ItemTitle, COUNT(*) As Cnt, MONTH(DatetimeUtc) As [Month]
      FROM PayPalHistory 
      WHERE DateTimeUtc >= '2014-01-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2015-01-01' AND Net > 0.00
      GROUP BY ItemTitle, MONTH(DateTimeUtc)
   ) m on m.ItemTitle = b.ItemTitle
GROUP BY b.ItemTitle
```

There's still some repetitive code in here, but I think you'll agree it's a *huge* improvement over the original... and I have a lot more confidence this will actually work ;)

Comment: neat way of handling months in alternative version!

Comment: For the pivot the aggregate needs to be for a specific column, like count(mth) in your case, and values for the IN clause needs to be in brackets like [1],[2] etc. as identifiers can't start with a number.

Comment: You should write PIVOTs more often they are lots of fun.

Comment: @bluefeet I've just been so used to the SUM(CASE) method, and most of the time when I need them it's for dynamic data anyway.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I will use both depending on the day or question, I just have a [love-affair with pivots](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/topusers).  I've been told I have a problem. :)

Comment: Could you please add comma before [11] AS November in PIVOT Code? Also could you please add comma after b.ItemTitle (before first CASE) in alternative version? Don't you think that JOIN is redundant in alternative version as ItemTitle column is already in the table?

Comment: @PavelNefyodov Not quite. It ensures that all items show in the results, even if no sales were made this year. But I fixed the missing comma.

Comment: Hi Joel, ItemTitle is in the SAME table "PayPalHistory". You are querying "PayPalHistory" twice. Hope it is ok.

Comment: @PavelNefyodov Yes, I know. It's possible that not every item is sold during the year, but he wants to see data on those items regardless. The first query of the table is to create a projection of all possible items, so that the join to the next query of the table won't be able to filter them away.

Comment: Good point. Even though I had an impression (please see data in original code such as "DateTimeUtc < '2014-05-01'") that it is needed for one year only.

Answer (score 2):

This PIVOT query might be what you want, please give it a try:

```
SELECT 
    ItemTitle, 
    [January],  [February], [March],   [April], 
    [May],      [June],     [July],    [August], 
    [September],[October],  [November],[December]
FROM 
  (
  SELECT ItemTitle, DATENAME(MONTH, DateTimeUtc) Month
  FROM paypalhistory 
  WHERE Net > 0.0 AND DateTimeUtc >= '2014-01-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2015-01-01'
  ) AS p
  PIVOT ( COUNT (Month) FOR Month IN
    ( [January], [February], [March], [April], [May], [June], 
      [July], [August], [September],[October], [November], [December] )
  ) AS pvt
ORDER BY ItemTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)?

You could PIVOT on DATEPART(month, DateTimeUtc)...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ItemTitle
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-01-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-02-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As January
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-02-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-03-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As February
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-03-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-04-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As March
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-04-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-05-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As April
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-05-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-06-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As May
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-06-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-07-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As June
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-07-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-08-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As July
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-08-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-09-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As August
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-09-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-10-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As September
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-10-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-11-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As October
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-11-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2014-12-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As November
    , SUM( CASE WHEN DateTimeUtc >= '2014-12-01' AND DateTimeUtc < '2015-01-01' AND Net > 0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As December
FROM PayPalHistory
GROUP BY ItemTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

A count group by month filter by net and year to a temp @var table then pivot to your final select.
Could you try it? I can create a mini db here to help you, if you need.